Why does Terence Tao use a subset of a subset of $R$ in the definition of limit of a function?
I'm studying real analysis using the book Analysis 1 of Terence Tao.
He defines the limit of a function at a point as follow (Definition 9.3.6)

Definition 9.3.6 (Convergence of functions at a point). Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbf{R}$, let $f : X \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, $x_0$ be an adherent point of $E$, and let $L$ be a real number. We say that $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$, and write $\lim_{x \to x_0; x \in E} f(x) = L$, iff $f$, after restricting to $E$, is $\varepsilon$-close to $L$ near $x_0$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. If $f$ does not converge to any number $L$ at $x_0$, we say that $f$ diverges at $x_0$, and leave $\lim_{x \to x_0; x \in E} f(x)$ undefined.

It seems to me that this definition is too complicated, he has to go through a subset $E$ of a set $X$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. I can't understand why didn't he directly define the limit of a function by just using the set $X$ (which is more than enough I think). Could you please explain me the motivation to use the set $E$ in this definition ?
Thank you for your help!

I've converted your image to text.  In general, it's bad form to post images of text in questions (as opposed to images of diagrams such as graphs, which are necessary but should still have alt-text).  But at least you didn't just link to the image off-site, which would have been worse!

A function might be defined in a large domain $X$, but sometimes we are interested in getting close to a point $x_0$ just by points from a specific subset. For example, the floor function $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ has no limit at the point $x_0=1$ if you consider it as a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. However, if you restrict the domain of $f$ to the interval $[1,2]$ and see what happens when you get closer to $x_0=1$ using points inside that interval then the limit at the point exists and equals to $1$.
That being said, the definition is definitely more complicated than it should be. I took a look at the book now, and he actually defines what "$\epsilon$-close near $x_0$" means, otherwise the definition wouldn't be rigorous. Not sure why Terence Tao decided this is better than defining directly like pretty much any other book does: "for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$...".

Yes, it may be that TT drifted into excess detail here...

My guess is that the motivation is for this one definition to do basically anything we need to do with limits of real functions. It not only covers the ordinary $\lim_{x\to a}$ but also things like $\lim_{x\to a^+}$ and some even more specialized ideas (as in this answer). But with all this extra mechanics, I was surprised that Tao defines $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ separately.

@DavidK: Hello, can you tell me why do you think that the definition of Tao also covers the case for example $lim_{x \to a^+}$ ? I don't understand it very well. Thanks!

@InTheSearchForKnowledge One-sided limits like $\lim_{x\to a^+}$ are covered later in the chapter. If you still have trouble understanding it after reading Tao's explanation, you could ask a new question about it.

@InTheSearchForKnowledge :  The example in the answer is basically an example of a one-sided limit, specifically of $ \lim \limits _ { x \to 1 ^ + } { \lfloor { x } \rfloor } $, which may be defined as $ \lim \limits _ { x \to 1 ; x \in [ 1 , \infty ) } { \lfloor { x } \rfloor } $ using Tao's definition.  (Strictly speaking, that one-sided limit uses $ E = [ 1 , \infty ) $, while the example in the answer uses $ E = [ 1 , 2 ] $, but these are equivalent when approaching $ 1 $.)

I think introducing"$\varepsilon$-close" is great from a teaching point of view. It conveys in semi-natural language what we want to express by $\vert x-x_0\vert<\varepsilon$, making the definition more understandable, and it makes the process of finding a rigorous definition more apparent by pointing out the concept (something is close to something else), and the fact that it needs a rigorous formulation by introducing a definition of what "close" means.

Fix a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ with nonempty interior. Consider for example the function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$, defined as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{if}~x~\text{is irrational} \\ 
1 & \mbox{if}~x~\text{is rational}
\end{cases}
$$
Write $X = E \cup F$ where $E = X \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Then for any $x \in E$, then we have that $f$ converges to $1$ at $x$ in $E$, but NOT in $X$.
Informally, the additional qualification ``in E'' allows us to ignore some potentially undesirable behavior in the set $F = X \setminus E$.

The other answers have explained why you want the set $ E $, but I think that it's worth mentioning that there are ways that we could have avoided having two sets ($ X $ and $ E $) here.  Here's one alternative:

Definition 9.3.6 A. Let $f : \mathbf{R} ⇸ \mathbf{R}$ be a partial function, let $E$ be a subset of the domain of $f$, let $x_0$ be an adherent point of $E$, and let $L$ be a real number. We say that $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$, and write $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0; x \in E} f(x) = L$, iff $f$, after restricting to $E$, is $\varepsilon$-close to $L$ near $x_0$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. If $f$ does not converge to any number $L$ at $x_0$, we say that $f$ diverges at $x_0$, and leave $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0; x \in E} f(x)$ undefined.

Here we specify only the set $ E $; $ X $ is left implicit as the domain of $ f $.  But in order to do this, we have to allow $ f $ to be only a partial function.
Here's another way:

Definition 9.3.6 B. Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbf{R}$, let $f : X \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function, let $x_0$ be an adherent point of $X$, and let $L$ be a real number. We say that $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_0$, and write $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$, iff $f$ is $\varepsilon$-close to $L$ near $x_0$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. If $f$ does not converge to any number $L$ at $x_0$, we say that $f$ diverges at $x_0$, and leave $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ undefined.

Here all reference to $ E $ has been removed, and if you ever want it, then you have to talk explicitly about $ f | _ E $ and not just $ f $.  Notice that $ \lim \limits _ { x \to x _ 0 } f | _ E ( x ) $ by this definition is equivalent to $ \lim \limits _ { x \to x _ 0 ; x \in E } f ( x ) $ by Tao's definition.
Of course, you could combine these and avoid mentioning any sets at all:

Definition 9.3.6 C. Let $f : \mathbf{R} ⇸ \mathbf{R}$ be a partial function, let $x_0$ be an adherent point of the domain of $f$, and let $L$ be a real number. We say that $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_0$, and write $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$, iff $f$ is $\varepsilon$-close to $L$ near $x_0$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. If $f$ does not converge to any number $L$ at $x_0$, we say that $f$ diverges at $x_0$, and leave $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ undefined.

Now $ X $ is left implicit, $ E $ is forced to be $ X $, and you speak of $ \lim \limits _ { x \to x _ 0 } f | _ E ( x ) $ if you want a different $ E $.
